# ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle" - How to change app ID name

Tags: ios, upload, terminal, certificate, application-loader

I recently re-signed my app with another certificate (I do not have the source code, so I had to do this to upload it to the App Store).

When I tried to upload it, I got: ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx' for executable 'Payload/xxxxxxx.app/Xxxxxxxx'."" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)".

I read in other posts that my bundle ID has to match my new App ID, from the new certificate I just signed.

I need direct instructions on how change the bundle ID in the IPA file! Like, real step-by-step instructions (I'm kind of a newbie).

Can anyone help me??
Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem right now. In my case this error occured because I had in the Build Settings an entry that pointed to an old name of the app. This old name included a '+' sign which is obviously not allowed.

Comment: Yes, for me the problem was that I had in the build settings of my project a reference to an app file that contained a `+` sign. After removing this it worked.

Comment: Can you teach me how to change something like that from the ipa file without the source code?

Answer (score 3):

Before you **Product > Archive** check that you are using an AppStore Distribution Provisioning Profile. Go to **Build Settings > Code Signing** and change Distribution Identity for Release and Provisioning Profile for Release.

[image: Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile for Release]

Comment: Thanks! Uploading apps from 2010 and this trick always helps. Strange.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have the same problem, and I create a new provisioning profile and connected it in build setting. But I keeps getting the same error. Eny thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try manually deleting executable inside .bundle (SoftwareAssets.bundle/SoftwareAssets). Not sure if that is "ok to do", but saw that people are doing that even for Google bundle distributions :) Anyway you should test how app behave with that change.