# Error while uploading to App Store "Missing Code Signing Entitlements"

Tags: ios, xcode

While uploading on app store i am having the following error. Actually i have a project(having a distribution code signing certificate) calling a static library(is not code-signed). I am using XCode 6.0.1

iTunes Store operation failed.

"Missing code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'xxx.Resources' for executable 'Payload/yyy.app/Resources.bundle/Resources'."

Has anyone ever experienced this issue and help me out please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle" - How to change app ID name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347770/error-itms-9000-missing-code-signing-entitlements-no-entitlements-found-in-bu)

Comment: I have already specified the distribution certificate in the release section as well as the distribution profile but in vain

Comment: actually i also want to mention that the static library has a Resources folder. Is is allowed to have one in the library? Moreover the library does not have an info-plist file but the Resources does (Resources-info.plist)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my own bundle. What I did is to generate new bundle without executable inside of it.
For bundle target in Build Phase tab you should delete Compile Source Phase and Link Binary with Libraries Phase. By this, executable is not generated inside the bundle and fixed mentioned error.

If you're using some 3rd party bundle try manually deleting executable inside it. Not sure if that is "ok to do", but saw that people are doing that even for Google bundle distributions :) Anyway you should test how app behave with that change.

Comment: Nice!! I resolved the problem with your answer. Thank you very much!